# How to add css stylesheet to a QWebEngineView?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to follow this Qt [example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-stylesheetbrowser-example.html) for adding `CSS` stylesheet to a `QWebEngineView`, however, I'm getting this error:

```
use of undefined type 'QWebEngineScriptCollection'
```

at the line `ui.webEngineView->page()->scripts().insert(script);`

What I'm missing? Testing using `qt 6.4` `Visual Studio 2022`, the project can be reproduced by simply adding a `QWebEngineView` to the ui, and

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QWebEngineScript>

void MainWindow::insertStyleSheet(const QString& name, const QString& source, bool immediately)
{
    QWebEngineScript script;
    QString s = QString::fromLatin1("(function() {"\
        "    css = document.createElement('style');"\
        "    css.type = 'text/css';"\
        "    css.id = '%1';"\
        "    document.head.appendChild(css);"\
        "    css.innerText = '%2';"\
        "})()").arg(name).arg(source.simplified());

    if (immediately)
        ui.webEngineView->page()->runJavaScript(s, QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);

    script.setName(name);
    script.setSourceCode(s);
    script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript::DocumentReady);
    script.setRunsOnSubFrames(true);
    script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript::ApplicationWorld);
    ui.webEngineView->page()->scripts().insert(script);
}


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

Comment: Just add `#include <QWebEngineScriptCollection>` as per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginescriptcollection.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The correct include is:

```
#include <QtWebEngineCore/qwebenginescriptcollection.h>
```